# Only Outputs 1 Row from SQL Database (Using Foreach Loop in PHP)

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, loops, foreach

I have 500 rows of cryto data including coin name and symbol in Wordpress database.

I'm trying to output all of rows using foreach loop and shortcode.

However, I'm only getting "BTC" row which is the first row of the table.

[image]

My code is this.

```
<?php 
add_shortcode('call_CMC_table', function() {
    global $wpdb;
    $all_coin_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}cmc_listing_data");

    foreach ( $all_coin_data as $print_data ) {
        $db_name = $print_data->name;
        $db_symbol = $print_data->symbol;

        $output =
            '<div class="ht-container">
                <figure class="ht-post__content table">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Coin Name</th>
                            <th>Coin Symbol</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>'. $db_name .'</td>
                            <td>'. $db_symbol .'</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </figure>
            </div>';

        return $output; 
    }
}); 
?>
```

What did i do wrong in this code? **I want to loop "< td >" tags in the table**. *By the way, I'm learning concept of loop these days and I'm following [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51984/how-to-display-data-from-custom-table-in-wordpress-database).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return $output;` ends the function there and then, and returns the data to the caller. Because you've put that inside the loop, it will stop the function at the end of the first time the loop has run. No more records will be processed.

You need to

1. Move that `return` statement outside the loop, after the end of it. This will allow the loop to process all the rows before the function execution is ended.
2. Append to `$output` each time the loop runs, instead of overwriting it - by using `.=` (i.e. `$output .=`...).
3. Move outside the loop all other content which shouldn't be repeated, such as the table header and the opening and closing tbody tags

Complete code:

```
<?php 
add_shortcode('call_CMC_table', function() {
    global $wpdb;
    $all_coin_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}cmc_listing_data");

      $output =
            '<div class="ht-container">
                <figure class="ht-post__content table">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Coin Name</th>
                            <th>Coin Symbol</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>';

    foreach ( $all_coin_data as $print_data ) {
        $db_name = $print_data->name;
        $db_symbol = $print_data->symbol;

        $output .= '
          <tr>
            <td>'. $db_name .'</td>
            <td>'. $db_symbol .'</td>
          </tr>';
    }

    $output .=  '
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </figure>
    </div>';
    
    return $output; 
}); 
?>
```

Comment: thanks! With your help, I'm getting closer to my goal! However, is there a way to make only <td> tags loop? The code above repeats <thead> tag too.

Comment: Yes there is. If you want something not to processed in a loop, what do you think you should do with it? Things _inside_ the loop get looped, so.... can you guess the rest?

Comment: I will try to get < tr > tags out of the loop!

Comment: I don't think you need to remove the tr from the loop, unless you want everything on one row! But the table, thead tags and its inner content, and tbody opening and closing tags, should all be outside the loop because they do not need repeating.

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect what I think you need - take a look.

Comment: Hmm I'm keep trying to remove every tags inside the loop except tr tags, but it's hard for me 'cause I'm not familiar with combining PHP and HTML :( It will take some time.  I will try lol.

Comment: Well, see my update, it should give you what you need. But you know you can examine the raw HTML output in your browser (using its View Source feature or the Element Inspector in the Developer Tools) so you can see precisely what PHP is outputting (not just how the browser renders that to the user). That makes it a lot easier to debug and get the structure right.

Comment: Oh My Gosh, Thanks! It worked! I didn't know the variables can be used 3rd times ($output,$output,$output). I was doing like "$output =$output1+$output2" and was getting errors lol. I learned a lot of things today! Thanks!

Comment: Well, like i said in the first version of the answer, `.=` can be used to append extra data to an existing string variable. Maybe you should also [read the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) :-)

Comment: And `+` is a mathematical operator (to add two values together), not a string operator. So that would give you errors if you use it with HTML strings, because clearly you cannot compute the sum of two bits of text! Again a [different part of the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) comes in handy here. Maybe review the whole [operators section of the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) so you're aware what's available to you, and what it does. This is fairly important information you need to know about any programming language.

Comment: Thanks for your sincere advice. I think I really need to read and study PHP manual! I will read PHP manuals including the page you linked. Thank you so much and god bless you!